# Removing Duplicates while Maintaining values in (2) Other Columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to remove duplicates by req_id, but need to keep the specific req_id that have values of (1) in the Offer_accepted or Offer_rejected colulmns. I tried messing around with Tidy package, but couldn't quite figure out how to do this properly.

[image]

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(req_id = c(335, 335, 335, 335, 336, 336, 336, 
337, 337, 337, 337), Offer_accepted = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Offer_rejected = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe we could it this way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(df[,2:3])>=1)
```

```
  req_id Offer_accepted Offer_rejected
   <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1    335              1              0
2    336              0              1
3    337              0              1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `if_any` in `filter` and add `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter(if_any(starts_with('Offer'),  ~.x == 1)) %>%
   distinct
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  req_id Offer_accepted Offer_rejected
   <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1    335              1              0
2    336              0              1
3    337              0              1
```

---

if the intention is to keep the 'req_id' all rows having at least a 1 in either of the 'Offer' columns, do a `group_by` and `filter` (in this case, it returns the full data)

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(req_id) %>%
   filter(any(if_any(starts_with('Offer'),  ~.x == 1))) %>%
   ungroup
```